# I use pycharm to define a list, name is src. But there is always a red wavy line under the variable name

Tags: python, pycharm

I use pycharm to define a list, name is src. Like this:

```
src = []
```

But there is always a red wavy line under the variable name. 
I want to know what cause the problem, and how to solve it.

[like this I can print it successfully!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzRkG.png)

Comment: What does it say when you hover over the red line?

Comment: Probably because you defined it but never used it anywhere else. PyCharm is trying to be helpful.

Comment: I just define a list like src = [] and only one line. Then I print it successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Its most probably due to the issue in the code above from this line maybe you are missing colon:, parenthesis () in for loop or if-else or indent issue.